# AngularJS: How to wait for $resource to finish?

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller:

```
app.controller('ProductDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$resource', 'Product', function($scope, $q, $resource, Product) {
  $scope.product = {};

  $scope.init = function(id)
  {
    $scope.product = Product.get({productId: id});

  }

  $q.all([$scope.product.$promise]).then(function() {
    $scope.selected_color = $scope.product.products_colors[0];
  });

  // $scope.selected_color = $scope.product.products_colors[0];

}]);
```

And a factory:

```
app.factory('Product', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource("/api/products/:productId", {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true},
  });
}]);
```

However, when I load the page it gives me this:

```
Error: $scope.product.products_colors is undefined @http://localhost:3000/assets/products/controllers/productscontroller.js?body=1:11:5 qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then/wrappedCallback@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:11499:15 qFactory/ref/<.then/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:11585:11 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12609:9 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12421:15 $RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:12713:13 bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:1420:9 invoke@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:3919:7 bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:1419:1 bootstrap@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:1432:5 angularInit@http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:1345:5 @http://localhost:3000/assets/angular.js?body=1:21818:5 jQuery.Callbacks/fire@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3100:1 jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3212:7 .ready@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3424:3 completed@http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery.js?body=1:3454:3


return logFn.apply(console, args);
```

How would I wait until the $resource finishes loading? I want to set one of my $scope variables based on the result of Product.get(..). I know that `Product.get(..)` is returning and object with a `products_colors` property because console.log says so

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a callback:

```
Product.get({productId: id}, function(data) {
    $scope.product = data;
});
```